# Drupal Album/Photos modules error. Not show photos/image/uid

Tags: 7

www.sitename.com/photos/image/697 --> go... But, not show image and other content and blocks...

Error messages: 
1- Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/large/public/photos/image_1/6396455561366990133.jpg.

2- DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!.

3- format_date() /includes/common.inc dosyasının 2014 line) date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given.

Help me please...

Comment: looks like its due to permissions

Comment: not for permissions. Another reason.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the Photo Information Block being inactive; it has been now fixed.